# ruby on rails chat application over port 80 which is hosting site agnostic(no flash and websockets)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, faye

Wanted to build a chat like application(i.e bidirectional message passing to multiple connected clients). Looked at the Faye gem but it opens a new port apart from port 80.

The big problem is that if the client is behind firewall all access to other ports except 80 are restricted and not all the hosting sites provide the support.

The ActionController::Live component does not have any mechanism to register the clients so that the message can not be passed to the registered clients on a specific event occurance.

Looking for a solution where the alive clients are stored in a collection(array or somthing like that) and when any of the alive client sends a message then the collection can be iterated and the messages can be written on it. All of these must happen only through port 80.

Comment: Try using sockets for it - they provide you with full flexibility. However I am not sure whether using port 80 is a good idea - it is reserved for www http protocole.

Comment: Oh wait a minute, you want it to be ruby on rails application - so you want it to be both web app and a chat on the same port?

Comment: Exactly. Thanks for understanding.

Comment: I am not sure whether it is possible at all - to have a real-live chat you have to establish stable connection over given port. Port 80 will be served by web server which, AFAIK, does not support it. The best thing you can do would be some ajax based chat, where the browser would send mini-requests to a server every two seconds and get most recent messages from a server as a response.

Comment: Ah, eventually you might think of using push-state introduced in html5. There are not plenty of resources, but you could have a look at `jquery-pjax` gem. Note that your server have to support push_state feature.

Answer (score 1):

Good question - having implemented something similar, let me explain how it works:

---

**Connections**

A "live" web application is not really "live" at all - it's just got a persistent request; meaning it still works exactly the same as a "normal" Rails app, except clients don't close the connection (hence why you're interested in opening another port)

The way you handle the request is where the magic happens. This is as much to do with the client-side, as it is with Rails (server-side)

---

**Clients**

When you connect to a "chat" application, your browser is opening a live connection with the server. This will typically be done with either [server sent events (Ajax long polling)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-sent_events), or [web sockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket)

The way this works is to open the connection using the normal Rails [ActionDispatch middleware](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html), and then allow you to connect

If you've played with [ActionController::Live](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Live.html) functionality, you'll find that it's not a typical controller-action. It's actually a separate technology (like [resque](https://github.com/resque/resque) or [Redis](http://redis.io/)) which you call from another controller action. This gives room to do cool things with

---

**Server**

The way you'd handle something like this is to separate the "live" functionality and the "normal" Rails app. It's one of the [current down-falls of Rails](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fOI3EjsUEww) - in that it's probably better to implement something like `nodeJS` with `socket.io` to handle the live data (with an endpoint like `chat.yourapp.com`), whilst using Rails to handle authentication & authorization

From a server perspective, its job is to handle incoming & outgoing requests -- not to handle persistent connections. So I guess you may want to look at ways you could "outsource" the websocket connectivity. Admittedly, my experience is slightly thin in this area, so you may do well searching the net

---

**Solutions**

We've had a lot of success using a third-party system called [Pusher](http://pusher.com)

This is a web socket system which allows you to open a persistent connection as a client, and integrates with Rails in a similar way to Redis (you can push to it)

This means you can host the "chat" application with Rails (`http://yourapp.com/chat`), send the messages to your Rails app (http://yourapp.com/chat/send), and **handle the incoming chats** from pusher (or similar)

Comment: :- Web Sockets can not be used since all of the clients are going to be android webview(has no websockets support), hence Pusher is not an option.

Comment: You're going to have to open a persistent connection somehow. Rails can't do it without client-side support

Comment: That is not a problem(clients can do a xmlhttprequest). But the problem is implementing websockets from client side. And pusher is a paid product, which is not a problem. But not willing(|worth) to pay for an idea that is not yet tested. Looking for free solution

Comment: Pusher is free for a certain level!! I'd definitely try Pusher out - but I'm not sure with the Andoid webview support, as you've alluded to

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to use my open source comet web server (https://github.com/TorstenRobitzki/Sioux). There is a ruby web chat example. I use this to implement an interactive role playing map with rails (http://dungeonpilot.com).

Comment: The dungeonpilot.com looks Cool. Excatly trying to build that kind of app. But not sure wheather it is hosting server agnostic. Who is the hosting provider for the dungeonpilot.com

Comment: You need access to your own server. Dungeonpilot is hosted of aws/ec2.